# Is SQL Management Studio 2012 avaliable, without Engine itself?

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

On my dev machine, I have SQL Management Studio 2008 R2 installed. I tried to upgrade to SSMS 2012 Express, setup finished but nothing happened.

Is it possible to get SQL Management Studio 2012 without occurring a license on the Database Engine itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Installing SSMS 2012 isn't really an upgrade, it's a separate installation of a newer version, so you basically have SSMS 2008 R2 *and* SSMS 2012 installed side by side.

Besides SSMS 2012 Express, you can also install [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg427686) which is a free "integrated environment for database developers to carry out all their database design work for any SQL Server platform".